# Copying shortcuts to the desktop

Tags: powershell

ALL,

I'm working on the program which installs itself in the user selected directory and then creates a shortcuts in the Start Menu for all users. The shortcuts are placed in the folder named by the following scheme:

```
<foo barx.y.z>
```

where "foo bar" is the name of the software and the "x.y.z" is the version number.

After installing we run the configuration scripts written in the PowerShell.

Its been decided that those shortcuts needs to be present on the user Desktop as well. So I thought that the easiest and the forward compatible solution would be to just copy those shortcuts at the end of the configuration scripts.

However, when I start the "Command Prompt" terminal inside Windows {7} and tried to do this:

```
copy "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\foo *" c:\Users\igor
```

I got an error message saying that the system cannot find the file specified.

Can someone shed some light lights? What is the proper way of copying this stuff? Or since I will do it inside PowerShell script everything will be good?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess the obvious question  is, does, 'c:\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\' contain something that matches 'foo *'?

Comment: @thepip3r, yes, when I open Windows Explorer I can see the folder named "foo barx.y.z" inside that path.

Comment: this worked for me.  copy 'C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\cam *' (mkdir 'C:\users\myuser\Desktop\test').  if it's not working for you then either source doesn't exist or the target doesn't exist.

Comment: @thepip3r, can you try to copy something from the "Start Menu" folder?

Comment: copies fine for me.  Are you running this as an elevated cmdshell or powershell?  access to the folder requires admin rights.

Comment: @thepip3r, I tried just from a regular "Command Prompt" running as a regular user and as an Administrator. Next step is PS.

Comment: can you "cd" to the directory?  ProgramData is a hidden directory and sometimes windows won't search or "see" hidden folders unless you have them turned on in Windows Explorer:  View -> Options -> View-tab, show hidden files and folders.

Comment: @thepip3r, surprisingly enough I can "cd" to that directory from the regular user command prompt window, not even an admin one.

Comment: @thepip3r, I just tried inside the PS and the command worked. So, I guess its some kind of limitation of Command Prompt window.

Answer (score 1):

Igor, you can try do something like this (maybe it help you):

```
 copy "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\*Hyper-V*" "c:\Users\$env:UserName" -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Very close, you need Desktop in the path as well if you want it to actually go the current user's desktop, e.g., `copy "c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Ghidra.lnk" "c:\Users\$env:UserName\Desktop" -Recurse -Force`